# Pester 5: Automate It

Tags: powershell, pester

For my hobby project [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression), I am rebuilding my test (Pester 5) script. I would like to automate the [`It`](https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/commands/It) (and possibly the [`Context`](https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/commands/Context) part) as there are large number of syntax formats to test for and the function actually roundtrips which `&([ScriptBlock]::Create("$Expression"))`. For a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I am using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.1) which roundtrips with [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1).
My goal for this question is basically to create an ***easy*** test syntax whether the concerned function correctly roundtrips, e.g.:

### `Test -Compress '{"a":1}'`

I would like to do something like this:

```
Function Test ([String]$Json, [Switch]$Compress, [String]$It = $Json) {
    $Context = if ($Compress) { 'Compress' } Else { 'Default' }
    $Object = ConvertFrom-Json $Json
    Context $Context {
#       BeforeEach {
#           $Compress = $True
#           $Json = '{"a":1}'
#           $Object = ConvertFrom-Json $Json
#       }
        It $It { ConvertTo-Json -Compress:$Compress -Depth 9 $Object | Should -Be $Json }
    }
}

Describe 'Syntax check' {

    Test -Compress '{"a":1}'

}
```

but this results in errors like:

```
Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery finished in 35ms.
[-] Syntax check.Compress.{"a":1} 15ms (13ms|2ms)
 RuntimeException: The variable '$Compress' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
 at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Test.ps1:6
Tests completed in 140ms
Tests Passed: 0, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

Enabling the commented-out hardcoded `BeforeEach` returns the expe*c*ted results:

```
Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery finished in 32ms.
[+] C:\Test.ps1 197ms (80ms|88ms)
Tests completed in 202ms
Tests Passed: 1, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

I would like to put `It` (and `Context`) in a function and control them with arguments so that I can do a simple test like `Test -Compress '{"a":1}'`. Unfortunately, I got completely lost in the new Pester discovery scopes and start wondering whether this is actually possible at all with Pester 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the variables of interest are only referenced inside the  *nested* script block (the one passed to `It`), not the outer one (the one passed to `Context`).

A simple solution is to call the `.GetNewClosure()` method on the outer script block, which forms a closure around the calling scope's local variables:

```
Function Test ([String]$Json, [Switch]$Compress, [String]$It = $Json) {
    $Context = if ($Compress) { 'Compress' } Else { 'Default' }
    $Object = ConvertFrom-Json $Json
    Context $Context {
        It $It { ConvertTo-Json -Compress:$Compress -Depth 9 $Object | Should -Be $Json }
    }.GetNewClosure() # This captures $Json, $Compress, $It, and $Object
}

Describe 'Syntax check' {
    Test -Compress '{"a":1}'
}
```

Note that the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure) are very terse at the moment, but the conversation in [GitHub issue #9077](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9077) suggests that the script block returned by `.GetNewClosure()` runs in a newly created *dynamic (in-memory) module*.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it using the `-TestCases` parameter:

```
Function Test ([String]$Json, [Switch]$Compress, [String]$It = $Json) {
    $Context = if ($Compress) { 'Compress' } Else { 'Default' }
    $Object = ConvertFrom-Json $Json
    Context $Context {
        $TestCase = @{ Params = @{ Compress = $Compress; Object = $Object; Json = $Json } }
        It $It -TestCases $TestCase { 
            param($Params)
            ConvertTo-Json -Compress:$Params.Compress -Depth 9 $Params.Object | Should -Be $Params.Json
        }
    }
}

Describe 'Syntax check' {

    Test -Compress '{"a":1}'

}
```

(But I am still open to other suggestions, espessially if it appears that I overlooked something obvious)